# Overcoming firestore update slight delay

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What I'm trying to do is -
I'm getting a click from users on different clients,
and I need to know which one was the first to click.

I have a document that clients write to,
and my idea was to let clients change it, as long as it's an empty string.
Otherwise, if it's already filled (with a user id), you cannot apply a change.
This way, I'll be able to know which user has clicked first.

The problem with this solution, is that it's client sided,
and there's a slight delay, causing users that didn't click first,
to update their user id, because when they clicked, the real first user wasn't updated yet.

Now, I'm new to firestore & firebase, and my question is,
is there a way to overcome this problem?

I had another idea, to basically let all clients send current time to firestore,
and then check who is first, but I wonder if there's a way to go with my first idea, and make it work.

thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could benefit from the *atomicity* of **transactions** (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

The transaction would look like this:

- read the string field
- if it is empty, write and return a 'first in success', if it is not, return a 'someone already there'
- If someone is already doing a transaction on this field, retry the transaction until the other transaction is terminated (firestore will automatically do that for you)

Comment: Wouldn't the problem still exist though?  It might show up as empty just like it does now, since there's a slight delay

Comment: If I understand well: a user could overwrite the ```firstToClick``` string if he clicks when another user has already clicked? And write his ID in ```firstToClick```  field instead of the other user (that was actually first)? If so, transaction atomicity would not permit that because you would systematically read from the database before changing it, checking for an empty string. If you succeed to write on it, you can be sure to be the only user writing on it with the implementation above. If they are both entering the transaction before sending it, only one of the 2 users will complete it.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. So basically; user1 clicks, checks that the string is empty (it is), his id is being updated in the field; Meanwhile, user2 clicks just after user1 did, checks that the string is empty (**it is**, since user1 id wasn't updated just yet), his id is being updated in the field.

Comment: From the doc: "For example, if a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction." So yes, it would not happen. Latest user will get its transaction retried and finally return 'there is something in the string, I can't write to it'

Comment: Okay now this is interesting, I'm going to try it out and let you know how it worked, thx!

Comment: From what I've tried right now, it seems to be working. Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the date validation, but doing it on the client side wouldn't be very safe, because variations in local times could cause users to incorrectly be identified as early or late. To solve that I see two options:

1. The first one would be creating an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) where you could get the server date and send it to the database. That way you are not influenced by the local date on your users' devices. You could also do the same by hosting this code anywhere you want and calling it with HTTP, the Cloud Function is just easier.
2. The other option would be first saving the date and the user to Realtime DB. It was created for realtime applications, so it will probably be faster than Firestore to write. You can then create a [DB Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) that would get the date and send it to Firestore, and there you can validate which user saved first.